# PDOException on Article page : Base table or view not found

Tags: 7, database

In my Drupal site, when I tried to save an article page I'm getting the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table  'novitawe_icpasld.field_revision_field_tags' doesn't exist:
>   DELETE FROM   {field_revision_field_tags} WHERE (entity_type =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (entity_id =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND (revision_id =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_2) AND (language IN
>   (:db_condition_placeholder_3)) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0]
>   => node [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 138 [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => 138  [:db_condition_placeholder_3] =>
>   und ) in field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (line 382 of
>   /home7/novitawe/public_html/icpasld/modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module)

Could anyone please let me know how can I solve this issue without affecting any of my DB because this site is live.
.

Comment: Have you checked your database to see if **field_revision_field_tags** exists? (Always confirm the error message is accurate.)

Comment: I just check my DB and there no table exist name with "field_revision_field_tags" do you know how to create this table structure ?

Comment: create a taxonomy term reference field with name `field_tags`

Comment: When you created the 'tags' field, two tables (field_data_field_tags and field_revision_field_tags) were created to hold the information. If the first table is present but the second is not, use a statement like 'CREATE TABLE field_revision_field_tags AS SELECT * FROM field_data_field_tags;' to replace the missing table. If both are missing, then you should restore your database from your latest backup.

Comment: @Ayesh K - If the error is showing, the field has already been created and the database is corrupt. If he tries to recreate the field before trying to recover, he might lose all existing information. Better to begin with the restoration attempt, then move to more drastic measures if restoration is not possible.

Comment: Yes, your initial instruction worked fine that creating duplicate as field_data_field_tags table. The article page is now saving successfully but following error shows on the saved artical `pageNotice: Undefined property: stdClass::$comment_count in comment_node_page_additions() (line 724 of /home7/novitawe/public_html/icpasld/modules/comment/comment.module). Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$comment_count in comment_node_page_additions() (line 724 of /home7/novitawe/public_html/icpasld/modules/comment/comment.module)`

Answer (score 0):

As per [@Triskelion comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64192/pdoexception-on-article-page-base-table-or-view-not-found#comment69734_64192):

When you created the 'tags' field, two tables (`field_data_field_tags` and `field_revision_field_tags`) were created to hold the information. If the first table is present but the second is not, use a statement like `CREATE TABLE field_revision_field_tags AS SELECT * FROM field_data_field_tags;` to replace the missing table. If both are missing, then you should restore your database from your latest backup.

If the error is showing, the field has already been created and the database is corrupt. If he tries to recreate the field before trying to recover, he might lose all existing information. Better to begin with the restoration attempt, then move to more drastic measures if restoration is not possible.